# I want the function name and body of that function from a javascript to get parsed out into a separate file. How do I do that using Java?

Tags: javascript, java, parsing

I have the following sample code:

```html
<Script>
 var lastEntdFld ;
     var fldobj ;
     var Args ;
     var errormsg ;
      
     
     function InitJSvar(){
   try {
        //Some texts
       }catch(e){}
    } 
</script>
```

**After parsing I want the following code:**

```
function InitJSvar(){
   try {
        //Some texts
       }catch(e){}
    }
```

How can I do that using Java?

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: What does com_init_values() do? Where is the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes. I tried using Mozilla Rhino tool. @X.L.Ant

That's some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by writing your own Parser for javascript and exporting the result into a new file with a filewriter. I think this would be the easiest way to do it.

Also if your script is in a HTML You can use [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/) and manual parsing.

Comment: the code is in separate JS file. I want only the function name and body to get separated. Any hint or idea of how to do that would be nice.

Comment: Then i would guess, that the simpliest way to that, is to read in the JS-file and parse it with a Parser on your own. Look for the"function" key- word and copy all of it's body till it's closing '}' and then write the result to a seperate file.

Comment: Thank you @grahan But actually I am looking for any already available tool for the same.